# Getting the features names form selectKbest

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, nlp, feature-selection

I used Scikit learn `selectKbest` to select the best features, around 500 from 900 of them. as follows where d is the dataframe of all the features.

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, chi2, f_classif
X_new = SelectKBest(chi2, k=491).fit_transform(d, label_vs)
```

when I print `X_new` it now, it gives me numbers only but I need name of the selected features to use them later on.

I tried things like `X_new.dtype.names` but I did't got back anything and I tried to convert `X_new` into data frame but the only columns names I got were

```
1, 2, 3, 4...
```

so is there a way to know what are the names of the selected features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you could do it, using `get_support()`:

```
chY = SelectKBest(chi2, k=491)
X_new = chY.fit_transform(d, label_vs)
column_names = [column[0]  for column in zip(d.columns,chY.get_support()) if column[1]]
```

From @AI_Learning 's answer you could get the column names by:

```
column_names = d.columns[chY.get_support()]
```

Comment: thanks. I have already finished with the project and I used a different route. however this is also very helpful for the future. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.get_support()` param of feature_selection, to get the feature names from your initial dataframe.

```
feature_selector = SelectKBest(chi2, k=491)
d.columns[feature_selector.get_support()]
```

Working example:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, chi2
X, y = load_digits(return_X_y=True)
df = pd.DataFrame(X, columns= ['feaure %s'%i for i in range(X.shape[1])])

feature_selector = SelectKBest(chi2, k=20)

X_new = feature_selector.fit_transform(df, y)
X_new.shape

df.columns[feature_selector.get_support()]
```

Output:

> Index(['feaure 5', 'feaure 6', 'feaure 13', 'feaure 19', 'feaure 20',
>          'feaure 21', 'feaure 26', 'feaure 28', 'feaure 30', 'feaure 33',
>          'feaure 34', 'feaure 41', 'feaure 42', 'feaure 43', 'feaure 44',
>          'feaure 46', 'feaure 54', 'feaure 58', 'feaure 61', 'feaure 62'],
>         dtype='object')

Comment: thanks. I have already finished with the project and I used a different route. however this is also very helpful for the future. thanks.